HoloISO/Archlinux Syncing the icu package results in the next boot becoming an endless black screen
I've done -Suy syncs after syncing the icu package, which should prevent conflicts as far as I know. I've used system-update-pacman combined with the download only options to perform the upgrade after a reboot, but that doesn't ever seem to actually upgrade the packages at all.
Hardware
Processors: 4xAMD Ryzen 3 2300x Quad-Core Processor
Memory: 7.7GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon RX 570
